# Running Python Scrapers and Database in online environment

Tags: python, database, phpmyadmin, web-scraping, storage

I hope that this question is not stupid but I am a beginner and I can hardly find good suggestions for what I need.

I run python webscrapers that crawl data from several platforms. So far the whole system is running locally on my Mac. As I will me travelling and need to check the consistency of my scrapers that will operate on a daily basis for at least a month I need to find another solution.

My requirements are:
* Storage for MySQL Database (Would love to use PhPMyAdmin to administrate)
* Enough Processing Power for Python Scrapers
* Necessary Python Modules can be installed
* Data can be accessed at any time and data dumps can be created

I have already found providers like AktiveState (http://www.activestate.com/) or PiCloud (http://www.picloud.com/). They seem to be solutions for the processing of the code.
Does anyone have experience with them?

Can somebody give me a tip for good storage that can communicate with these platforms?

As I am a beginner, I really need something that is easy to use. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Amazon Web Services, Heroku, or Google App Engine, though your choice will depend on your level of expertise and your cost basis.

Heroku is the easiest to use but most costly, followed by GAE, and then AWS is the hardest to use but cheapest.